# Is it possible to order the questions by user reputation?

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

I am new to programming and do not know much syntax. However, I am happy to answer questions. I have noticed I normally answer questions from users of lower reputation with greater ease. Is there a way to order the 'new questions' by the asker's reputation? If there isn't can you add one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network in general, we try to focus on the questions themselves rather than who is asking them. Because of that, sorting questions by user reputation is not something that exists and it's not something that's likely to be implemented by the SE team.

That said, if you're looking for questions to answer, you might want to consider favoriting some tags:

[image: Favorite tags]

By doing that, you should get more questions that you're interested in and able to answer in your feed, and you'll find yourself able to answer more questions over time. Note that questions tagged with one or more of your favorite tags will also appear highlighted on the questions page. You can visit [your tag prediction report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current) to find out what tags the system thinks you may be interested in.

Also take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to find more questions that interest you.

Comment: Also you can find unanswered questions in http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest, which could be another good list of targets to answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can browse new questions from new users would be to [review first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) which is a review queue which consists of posts from new users. By reviewing first posts you are helping improve Stack Overflow and also browsing the posts by new users which can contain questions you might be interested in answering. But to [access review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) you need 500 or more reputation. AstroCB's answer is great to follow the earn the required 500 reputation.

Comment: 1) He doesn't have enough rep to access the queues 2) being a new and inexperienced user, he wouldn't be able to actually help review these posts appropriately anyway.

Comment: @Servy I hope you read the whole answer and I can see that he has a reputation of 62 hence I mentioned about the the required reputation and how one can achieve the required reputation it. I added this answer keeping in mind of any other users who might view this question later would know about this. The user will earn experience by the time him will earn the required reputation hence there is a privilege is earned only after 500 reputation.

Comment: Did you read the question?  He's asking how to order questions by the user's reputation.  This is not that.  It's also a place to go to improve potentially problematic posts, and to provide feedback for new users, not a place to go to find questions to answer.  Items in these queues are highly likely to not be answerable questions; that's the reason they're in a queue in the first place.

Comment: @Servy I did read the question. If according to you this answer is not related to the question so is the other answer which mentions about how Stack Overflow works, how to add favorite tags which is also not about how to order questions by user reputation. I did mention that the review queue is used to improve Stack Overflow by which I mean make them answerable by editing them. While reviewing First posts I come across posts in my domain knowledge which I improve and answer them if I can. whats wrong with that?