# Can I search questions by reputation?

Tags: support, questions

I've never seen this website, but looks like the place to talk about Stack Overflow, so here I go.

I recently started answering questions because I learn doing it, and honestly, it's fun when interesting questions come up. However, 90% of the time the questions are made by people who just started to learn a programming language.

Sometimes I get tired just trying to understand a question: unclear question, awful formating, no description at all but 300 lines copy/pasted. So, is there any way, to show new questions with a reputation filter? For example, 100+ reputation user's questions?

I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287338/is-it-possible-to-order-the-questions-by-user-reputation) question about sorting, and even though it's related, it's not the same, and it's 1 year old, so I needed to ask.

I know it's not a big deal, but explaining the basics so many times is so boring/exhausting.

---

**EDIT:** Looks like people don't really share my point of view. I will not remove in case someone has the same answer, but I will close it (if I can), otherwise, some mod do it please. Thanks.

Comment: Reputation of the user isn't necessarily directly related to the quality of a question. Don't start getting arrogant regarding having a few 100 rep.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ Of course not, but 95% of the times, questions related to Java or Android are.

Comment: @JustDoIt Check my activity. Posted a question 1 year ago and haven't used it till this week.

Comment: @UDKOX Sure. Just react with the tools you have at hand. Flag as duplicate / off topic etc., downvote, may be leave a comment. If the question bores you at all and you just don't want to take any action, simply move on.

Comment: You could try looking in the bounty section or http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered and sorting by votes. The whole "finding an interesting question" is problematic to everyone, so, at least you aren't alone.

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks! Will check it out!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not to ruin the spirit, but I'm pretty sure there *is* a correlation between rep and question quality. Those who *can't* ask good questions get banned and/or stuck at 1 rep. Those who *can* ask good questions end up getting positive rep from them. While the correlation may not be very strong, I'm pretty sure it's there, even if just comparing 1 rep and > 1 rep users.

Comment: @Mysticial Of course there's a statistical relation, but that doesn't mean it always applies for every question coming from a low rep user.

Comment: @Mysticial - There is a steep drop off after a few hundred reputation points in closure rates from something like 5.6% down to 3.5%, which is to say I agree with you.

Comment: @Mysticial, depends on the train trailing back or not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not a fact that 100+ rep users make better questions that 1 rep users. Agreed. I was trying to make my 30 minutes of daily StackOverflow more enjoyable. Filtering rep was an idea I had that would satisfy me. I have been spending my time trying to help others just like you. I am top 1% this week and feels good, but I wanted to get points for good questions, not solving `NullPointerExceptions`. If you figure out a better approach I am the first one to try it out, but no need to get aggro with `Don't start getting arrogant regarding having a few 100 rep`.

Comment: The downvotes indicate that people don't think this would be a good idea, but meta is the right place to ask so don't be discouraged :)

Comment: @Ajean That's something. Thanks : )

Comment: I'd like a way to find truly puzzling questions easier.  Sometimes I just really want something that will tax my brain; anecdotally, I find this usually comes with a rep of 20k or so...that's my interest in sorting by rep (which is how I found this thread).  Maybe we just need a tag of [hard] for people who are confident they've run into something tricky.  (Not just some homework quesiton)

Answer (score 1):

As from your title

> Search questions by reputation

That's probably the wrong approach for finding interesting and useful questions to answer.

Always judge question quality by it's content, and not get biased by the rep of the OP.

---

Whilst it often correlates, that new or low rep users on Stack Overflow ask low quality questions, that isn't a paradigm hammered in stone.

> Sometimes I get tired just trying to understand a question: not clear question, awful formatting, not description at all but 300 lines copy/pasted.

You'd miss a significant amount of appropriately and correctly asked questions applying such filter.

---

Downvote, vote (flag) to close as off-topic.

> So, is there any way, to show the new questions with a reputation filter ?

The user's reputation doesn't necessarily correlate with the questions quality. Though these parameters often do correlate in reality, they are orthogonal from the semantical POV.

> For example, 100+ reputation user's questions ?

I've seen train wreck LQ questions asked by +100K users, and useful pearls asked about completely fresh OPs (user for today, rep 1).

So what?

Comment: `That's probably the wrong approach for finding interesting and useful questions to answer.` I disagree strongly. While it's true that reputation doesn't equate to skill, you have a much higher chance of finding better questions when they're asked by higher reputation people. Since false negatives are not that important (if we skip a few good questions), it's quite a valid approach to find good questions.

Comment: @Rob it's difficult to find reasons why such filtering is a bad idea for users like yourself,  That's because it's actually a very good idea, it's just that SO management need to ensure that it not happen on a large scale, else the one or two good questions amongst the the thousands of 'Member since today' do-my-homewoks will not get any attention, SO will become stale and the business will fail.

Comment: @Rob: "*While it's true that reputation doesn't equate to skill*" No; that right there is the end of the debate. If reputation is not a *reliable* measurement of "skill", if it is not sufficient to ensure that bad questions are avoided and good questions are always seen, then it is a poor metric and we should not encourage its use. Furthermore, what good does such a filter do? You may as well just divide Stack Overflow into two sites.

Comment: @NicolBolas Let me rephrase, then. Reputation does not *directly and unequivocally* equate to skill. But there definitely *is* a correlation. It's no secret that the top users on SO are vastly more knowledgeable than the average developer. Just because a metric does not give you a 100% success rate, does not mean it is useless. As for whether or not the filter would be good for the site; I had no comment on. I simply responded to the idea that it's a bad approach - which I disagree with. Do note the question is "Can I search by reputation?", not "Let's add filters to hide low rep questions"

Comment: @NicolBolas while I agree that it shouldn't necessarily be encouraged, and that widespread use of that metric to filter questions would amount to SO "class warfare", I just came from [VBA] where low quality questions are rampant. The low quality question to low rep correlation is pretty accurate :'(

Answer (score -1):

What about [such query](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A0+created%3A2016-05-01..)?

```
is:q answers:0 created:2016-05-01..
```

Of course you can change a date and add some tags.

Comment: Thanks! I never noticed that ability. Now if we could just add `rep:>200` (or something like that) we could skip over the pleas for homework help.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Chloe, seems like I meant, that you can sort this list by votes, so you'll get free interesting unanswered questions.

Comment: Title of post is: `Can I search questions by reputation?`

Comment: @Chloe, the title isn't the only thing the post have. I think it's the closest way of getting what he actually wants. If you can propose something better, fill free to post an answer.